# Jenkins plugin development - how to check if plugin is executing on Jenkins Master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have implemented a custom Pipeline-compatible Jenkins plugin which extends `SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution` class. I would like to implement particular logic around execution on Jenkins Master vs Jenkins Slave. How can I check from within the plugin code if the step is running on Master?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the plugin execution happens on a build executor in a Jenkins slave. But, to verify which part of the plugin code execute on master/slave, you can use the following.

1. Find out an environment variable that is specific to your slave. I use `NODE_NAME` env var for this purpose. You can find out all available environment variables in your Jenkins instance via http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html (replace the host name to match your instance). In there, you'll find the NODE_NAME:

> **NODE_NAME**
>
> Name of the agent if the build is on an agent, or "master" if run on master

2. Log/print the environment variable. Following is a code snippet that shows how you can print it. In there, I show the example using the [setUp method of hudson BuildWrapper](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-jenkins-m2release-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/m2release/M2ReleaseBuildWrapper.java#L181) for reference.

   ```
   @Override
   public Environment setUp(final AbstractBuild build, final Launcher launcher,
                   final BuildListener listener) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      String node = System.getenv("NODE_NAME");
      String msg = "I'm executing on node: " + node;
      listener.getLogger().println(msg); //prints to build log
      logger.info(msg);           // slf4j logger - prints to catalina log/jenkins log
   }
   ```

Alternatively, you can also write the value into a file, and read the value from there.

Comment: Despite what the manual says under the URL you pointed me to, `System.getenv("NODE_NAME")` returns `null` - not `master` or name of the agent.

Comment: That's a bit weird. Anyway, you can fallback to the alternative method. If your master and slaves are on distinct VMs, then you can see to which VM's file system it gets written into.

Comment: That, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be a reliable way of determing if the execution is happening on master or not.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was under the impression that you need to know this for development/debugging purposes. We certainly need a better way for production code. It'd be interesting to know what kind of high-level usecase you want to address in order to dig deep on this.